# Is there a mobile version available?

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering if there is a mobile version of the site available?

Answer (score 1):

There is a read-only version called StackMobile.  You can learn more about it here on this question called [iPhone/Mobile app and mobile-site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73964/155826).

The team is working on a 2.0 version with authentication and writing ability.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.